# rust/cargo read env from shell and reuse them instread of explicity setting them in front of command everytime

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to run a rust test with some env, like:

```
use std::env;
#[test]
fn test_case1() {
    env::var("ENV1").unwrap();
    env::var("ENV2").unwrap();
}

#[test]
fn test_case2() {
    env::var("ENV1").unwrap();
    env::var("ENV2").unwrap();
}
```

```
ENV1=ABC ENV2=123 cargo test test_case1
```

But I want to only set these env once and I can reuse them in the shell, like:

```
ENV1=ABC ENV2=123
echo $ENV1   // ABC
echo $ENV2   // 123
cargo test test_case1   // test_case1 will read ENV1, ENV2 then quit,
cargo test test_case2   // test_case2 will read ENV1, ENV2 too
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Hello, this article can help you? https://siciarz.net/24-days-rust-environment-variables/

Comment: Yes, you can persist environment variables in your shell and your tests will see them. Do you not know how to do that?

Comment: I just can't. It says `thread 'test_case1' panicked at 'called \`Result::unwrap()\` on an \`Err\` value: NotPresent', src/main.rs:170:22`.